# Is fixture the correct name for this?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Let's say I am writing specs for a program that processes a CSV downloaded from an external source.

Since I don't want my program to download the CSV file everytime I want to run my specs, I have saved it as spec/fixtures/downloaded_csv.csv and I am loading it before I run my specs.

Now the question is: what is the correct name for this in RSpec? Is this also a fixture? Or the name fixture is only valid for data loaded into a database (like rails fixtures for example).

Comment: yes, you can call it fixture. but since answers will be based on opinions, i don't think your question belongs here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fixtures Defined

Wikipedia defines a [test fixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture#Test_fixture_in_xUnit) as:

> [A]ll the things that must be in place in order to run a test and expect a particular outcome.

Some people make a distinction between data fixtures that are loaded during test setup, and file fixtures that are simply external assets. This may or may not be a useful distinction, and a CSV file could be used either way depending on the nature of your tests.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, the correct name for this is also a fixture. This is where I would keep it.

We use something similar here as an session data fixture or JSON response from a 3rd party API.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that `fixture` is a good name for it. Fixtures are representations of your data source, and if your app is just processing a CSV file, that CSV file is your datasource. Therefore, fixture is fine. When it comes down to it, you can name it whatever you want :)